# Configuring Proton for SSL / TLS throwing openssl wrong version number and gRPC client error

Tags: ssl, lotus-domino, grpc, domino-appdev-pack

I'm kinda at a loss here.
Trying to set up proton with SSL / TLS access, but after creating the certificates with the (modified) shell scripts
supplied by the AppDev-Pack and linking the keyring and everything in notes.ini, I always seem to get
the error "Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error: 100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:
WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER".

Tried both a windows and linux server, as well as using the accessing node.js app with and without
certificates - but with no success.

Also tried the troubleshoot section of https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/proton-admin.html and it connected just fine,
but won't if i connect with node.js.

Looks like the error is thrown before a certificate is even checked?

In this example the error is thrown after trying to get a document by UNID.

[notes.ini (proton parts)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Y6TU.png)

[gRPC Client Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfSo1.png)

If someone has an idea how to fix that issue or where to start - that would really help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the modified scripts (with sensitive info redacted)?

Comment: It might also help if you could share the code to your test app.  with config info, but without any passwords, certs, or keys.

Comment: have you seen this ? http://blog.nashcom.de/nashcomblog.nsf/dx/appdevpack-security-setup-explained.htm?opendocument&comments

Comment: Problem was a missing secure flag, like Steve mentioned. I followed a tutorial where the credentials were set, but there was no secure flag as well, which i took for granted, that it'd work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the client side does not have the secure flag set. At least I get a similar stack when I try to connect without TLS when the server expects TLS.

See the `secure` attribute when calling [useServer](https://doc.cwpcollaboration.com/appdevpack/docs/en/domino-db-reference.html#useserver)() function, and you'll also need to provide the `credentials` attributes.

Comment: And that did the trick - had credentials added and everything, but the secure flag was missing - thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Any chance we can get a link to the tutorial which did not show the secure flag? Perhaps we can ask to have it updated. Thanks!

Comment: It was on http://oliverbusse.notesx.net/hp.nsf/blogpost.xsp?documentId=2FF2 with the linked testproject located on https://gitlab.com/obusse/proton_blog/blob/master/client_cert/app.js - already left him a comment :)